# Finding the smallest integer that is a factor of C?

Tags: java, numbers, factorization

I need help with this method
smallestFactor

`public static int smallestFactor(int C)`
This function takes as its argument an integer C, and it returns the smallest integer that is a factor of C, other than 1.

Parameters:  C - An integer to factor.

Precondition: C must be greater than 1.

Returns: The smallest factor of C.

```
public class Factor
{       
public static long smallestFactor(int C)
    {   
    for (int i = 2; i*i<= C; i++) 
    {   
        while (C % i == 0) 
        {
         System.out.print(i + " "); 
         C = C / i;
        }
    }
        return C;
    }
}
```

I need to find the smallest Factor 
but I'm not sure how to do it

Comment: the first i that you print is it.

Comment: This function prints all the factors in the increasing order right. So, just add a `break` statement in the while after the print.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `if` instead of `while`, and return `i` if you find it.

```
public static long smallestFactor(int C)
{
    for (int i = 2; i*i<= C; i++) 
    {   
        if (C % i == 0)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return C;
}
```

There are other improvements you could make, but that should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Small changes to your code- you were close!

```
public class Factor {

    public static long smallestFactor(int C) {

        for (int i = 2; i*i<= C; i++) {   
            if (C % i == 0) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value you need to return is your `i`, not `C`.

You should work through possible values of `i` in your loop, and `return` that value when you find that `C % i == 0`.

Note that for efficiency you should test 2, 3, and then every odd number thereafter.  There's no point testing (4, 6, 8, ...) if you already tested 2:

```
public static int smallestFactor(int C) {
    if (C % 2 == 0) return 2;  // C is even

    for (int i = 3; i * i <= C; i += 2) {
        if (C % i == 0) return i;  // odd factor found
    }

    return C;  // no factor found
}
```

In fact the most efficient algorithm would only test for *prime* factors, but I suspect that's beyond the scope of what you've been asked.

Answer (score 0):

Handling all exceptional cases, try this code:

```
public static long smallestFactor(int x)
{
    if(x < 1)  return -1;
    if(x == 1) return  1;

    for(int i=2; i<=x; i++)
       if(x % i == 0) 
          return i;

    return -1; // To stop compiler's complaints.
}
```